how to do integral in r
I have a data frame where each row represent a community with number of species and number of individuals:
n.species<- c(3,5,10,15,20)
n.indiv <- c(30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 750, 1000)
n.indiv <- rep(n.indiv, each = length(S))
df <- data.frame(S = rep(S, length(n.indiv) / length(S)), n.indiv)
df$margalef <- (df$n.species-1)/(log(df$n.indiv))
print(df)

I would like to calculate the integral of margalef  (df$n.species-1)/(log(df$n.indiv)) against n.indiv for each row.

are you looking for the stats::integrate() function?

The code is not reproducible, S is undefined.

You could use the following function to (numerically) calculate an integral:
trapint <- function (x, y, a, b) {
  if (length(x) != length(y))
    stop("length x must equal length y")
  y <- y[x >= a & x <= b]
  x <- x[x >= a & x <= b]
  if (length(unique(x)) < 2)
    return(NA)
  ya <- approx(x, y, a, ties=max, rule=2)$y
  yb <- approx(x, y, b, ties=max, rule=2)$y
  x <- c(a, x, b)
  y <- c(ya, y, yb)
  h <- diff(x)
  lx <- length(x)
  result <- 0.5*sum(h*(y[-1] + y[-lx]))
  return(result)
}

The parameters are:

x: the x values of your graph
y: the y values of your graph
a: lower integral border (from where to start integrating)
b: upper integral border (where to end integration)

Example
xvalues <- -10:10
yvalues <- -xvalues^2
# Integrate from 0 to 5
trapint(x=xvalues, y=yvalues, a=0, b=5)
## Result: -42.5

Be aware that this is an approximation of the integral and quite dependent on the resolution of your graph!
Compare this to the "real" solution here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integral+of+y%3D-x%5E2+from+0+to+5

You can use the cumtrapz function from the pracma package for the cumulative trapezoidal method.

Trapezoidal method is a basic method for numerical integration.
Cumulative means that you would like the integral up to each index.
pracma is a well-known package with applied math methods for integration and more.

Your code does not run, but here is an example on sample data.
x <- seq(0, pi, by = 0.1)
y <- sin(x)

y_int <- pracma::cumtrapz(x, y)[, 1]

data.frame(x, y, y_int)
#>      x          y       y_int
#> 1  0.0 0.00000000 0.000000000
#> 2  0.1 0.09983342 0.004991671
#> 3  0.2 0.19866933 0.019916808
#> 4  0.3 0.29552021 0.044626285
#> 5  0.4 0.38941834 0.078873213
#> 6  0.5 0.47942554 0.122315407
#> 7  0.6 0.56464247 0.174518807
#> 8  0.7 0.64421769 0.234961815
#> 9  0.8 0.71735609 0.303040504
#> 10 0.9 0.78332691 0.378074654
#> 11 1.0 0.84147098 0.459314549
#> 12 1.1 0.89120736 0.545948466
#> 13 1.2 0.93203909 0.637110788
#> 14 1.3 0.96355819 0.731890652
#> 15 1.4 0.98544973 0.829341048
#> 16 1.5 0.99749499 0.928488284
#> 17 1.6 0.99957360 1.028341713
#> 18 1.7 0.99166481 1.127903634
#> 19 1.8 0.97384763 1.226179256
#> 20 1.9 0.94630009 1.322186642
#> 21 2.0 0.90929743 1.414966517
#> 22 2.1 0.86320937 1.503591857
#> 23 2.2 0.80849640 1.587177146
#> 24 2.3 0.74570521 1.664887226
#> 25 2.4 0.67546318 1.735945646
#> 26 2.5 0.59847214 1.799642412
#> 27 2.6 0.51550137 1.855341088
#> 28 2.7 0.42737988 1.902485151
#> 29 2.8 0.33498815 1.940603552
#> 30 2.9 0.23924933 1.969315426
#> 31 3.0 0.14112001 1.988333893
#> 32 3.1 0.04158066 1.997468927

Created on 2024-06-12 with reprex v2.1.0
